# Oracle APEX Login case sensitivity

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am making my own authentication scheme for an app developed in APEX 5.1. The string for the username as it enters my code is being uppercased by default. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `APEX_AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN`? It accepts 3 parameters. The first two are trivial:

- p_username
- p_password

The third one is optional:

- p_uppercase_username IN BOOLEAN **DEFAULT TRUE**

which means that, unless you set it to `FALSE`, usernames will be converted to `UPPERCASE`.

So - set it to FALSE.